# Passing all input as single params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have created a search form

```
<%= form_tag url_for(:action => "index") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'fromdate' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'todate' %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

I need to pass all these values as a single params in my controller to model. This is my controller

```
def index
    @client = Customer.search
    #something like this @client = Customer.search(as_single_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
    end
  end
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Your view will return attributes in the `params` hash. You need to pull the attributes from the `params` hash (e.g., `params[:fromdate]`) and execute a suitable query using those parameters on the `Customer` data. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html for information regarding the query interface.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want more than `Customer.search(params[:fromdate], params[:todate])`

Comment: Depending on your `Customer` model, you may also be able to simply pass the entire `params` hash through: `Customer.search(params)`

Comment: @Shadwell If i have ten form fields is it good idea to pass all the tem params one by one? I am looking for alternate solution

Comment: That's why I wasn't clear on what you were trying to achieve. Perhaps if you expanded your `as_single_params` to show exactly what you want to pass through to search then it would be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in your view:

```
<%= text_field_tag "some_fields[]" %>
<%= text_field_tag "some_fields[]" %>
<%= text_field_tag "some_fields[]" %>
```

Then in your controller simply retrieve the values using:

```
some_fields = params[:some_fields] # this is an array
```

If you pass values as keys, Rails will give you a Hash:

```
<%= text_field_tag "some_fields[fromdate]" %>
<%= text_field_tag "some_fields[todate]" %>
```

In your controller you can do this now:

```
@clients = Customer.search(params[:some_fields])
       ^
```

I added an `s` to `@client` since you'll have probably more than one clients matching your criteria.

Comment: Ok in my model i used `fromdate = '2013-08-29'` and my query is `find_by_sql("select * from blah where fromdate=#{fromdate}")`. But i am unable to get from date inside the query its empty where i am wrong

Comment: Try `where("fromdate = ?", fromdate)`

Comment: It i use like what you mentioned am getting error as `wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)`

Comment: can you update your question with your actual code and the place where you do the query please.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form, all of the parameters you selected will be passed to the controller in the `params` hash. For example, `params[:fromdate]` and `params[:todate]`.

In your controller, if your `params` hash contains only `Customer` fields you want to search on (i.e., the form only has `Customer` fields defined, then you can do:

```
def index
  @clients = Customer.where(params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

Note that I show `@clients` since `where` will return a collection. You can select the first one (especially if you're sure there's only one) by doing this:

```
@client = Customer.where(params).try(:first)
```